# Initializing GraniteDS Tide framework

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, graniteds

I'm trying to work with GDS Tide framework. My basic code is this one :

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               preinitialize="Tide.getInstance().initApplication()">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import controllers.TestController;

        import events.TestEvent;

        import models.TestModel;
        import models.interfaces.ITestModel;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import org.granite.tide.Tide;


        [Bindable][Inject]
        public var testModel:ITestModel;

        Tide.getInstance().addComponents([TestController, TestModel]);


    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout />
</s:layout>

<s:Label text="{testModel.ab}" />
<s:Button click="dispatchEvent(new TestEvent());" label="test !" />
```

I can compile and run my code but when I'm launching my application, I see blank windows, my button or my label don't appear. No errors are fired.

When I change my code to this one :

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               preinitialize="Tide.getInstance().initApplication()" creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import controllers.TestController;

        import events.TestEvent;

        import models.TestModel;
        import models.interfaces.ITestModel;

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import org.granite.tide.Tide;


        [Bindable][Inject]
        public var testModel:ITestModel;


        protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            Tide.getInstance().addComponents([TestController, TestModel]);
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout />
</s:layout>

<s:Label text="{testModel.ab}" />
<s:Button click="dispatchEvent(new TestEvent());" label="test !" />
```

it works I see label and button but my label isn't initialized properly because my controller and model are added on `mx.events.FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` event.

What am I doing wrong please with the first (and recommanded) method ?

Comment: Can I see how you have defined controller and model? Are you following https://www.granitedataservices.com/public/docs/2.3.2/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.tideframework.html

Comment: Yes I followed docs. When I launch examples provided (and coded by GDS team) it's the same. When I use older GDS swc libraries (named granite-essential.swc) it's work. I don't understand why even if the workaround is just to use addComponents method in creationComplete event method. I don't understand why

Comment: I'm not a GraniteDS expert, but it seems to me that in your first example, Tide's `addComponents` is being executed before `initApplication`.  Is that deliberate?